# Safari 9 - flexbox align-self: flex-end doesnt work

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I am having trouble to align child element to the end of its parent element. Both are flex elements. Parent element has height: 100%, and the child has: align-self: flex-end.
This setup works in all major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE/Edge), but it does not work in Safari 9 (and some older versions which support flexbox too).

Here is how it looks:
[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MZ95.png)

Here is copy-paste example, you can see it works in Chrome, but in Safari its in the middle:

```
http://cdpn.io/usrbowe/pen/JXBjvv
```

The problem is that on .Row is align-items: center, which has higher priority in Safari, so it align child element on center.

Comment: It would be better if you could paste a working example to prove it.

Comment: ok, I added working example in codepen

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: I cleared out most all the unnecessary code to investigate this. Please do so when submitting questions, my friend. http://codepen.io/alexbea/pen/KzBXQJ. In CodePen you can have it use Autoprefixer, which alone goes a long way to make Sass easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

After stripping out most of the code not related to the problem, I realized it was not `align-items` that's giving you trouble here. It's `align-content`, which `align-self` does not override. You mentioned `align-items: center;` was taking precedence, but in the example you have `align-items: flex-start;` overriding `center` already. Regardless, that's not the problem.

It does seem to be a browser quirk, however. According to the trusty [flexbox spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#align-content-property) (and [my favorite flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))`align-content` should not have any effect on a single line flex container. For some reason in Safari it is, however.

Given the example, I suggest you remove `align-content` altogether. It doesn't seem like you're looking for it to actually center anything along the cross axis. The content used in the example supports that theory as well. If that's not correct and there should be other content involved that would play a part, please update the code example.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my Codepen demo. Reproduced here: https://codepen.io/alexbea/pen/RpaNQq